# How do I allow more than one user to read the output and enter commands for a program running in the Terminal remotely via SSH?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, minecraft, output, input

I've looked around and I've seen that some people recommended using Screen, but I don't exactly know what they meant. The program in question is a Minecraft server. I need it to be able to allow multiple people look at the console and enter commands. Each person will have a user account. The server JAR is inside a directory inside the root directory (but not in a home folder) and everyone in a certain group will be able to have read and write permissions to the folder in which the server is held in. I have tried RCON, and it seems like it does not work at the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

So, in short:

- Have multiple people with different user accounts
- Let more than one user access the console at a time
- Let the user read and write (commands) to the console
- If possible, on connection, display all messages from the server from that session's (session being from when the server JAR was started) start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually, the program "screen" allows you to do just that.

There are complete, step by step instructions on how to use it at

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=299286

(the thread is a bit old, so I checked, and it really works)

What you'll want to do is to open a screen as the article instructs, and then just run the program in there. Whenever a user is finished using the terminal, he should type crtl-a and crtl-d. This way he 'disconnects' from the screen, but it keeps running

Comment: I said screen in my text, but I did not know how to implement it. I'll try this out on my server. If it works, thanks! If not, still, thanks!

Comment: I am stuck on step 5. If I press Control + A it doesn't give me a ^A. Then when I type :multiuser on it says :multiuser: command not found. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind. I was being stupid. This works!